# How to share an entity and other entity can use it (one=>many)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes

First one is Employee

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the Second is Contract

```
public  class Contract 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

I need to store some kind of files into each contract and employee (one employee could have 0 or more files attached (his CV, scanned identity document, etc... ) and a contract could have 0 to many files attached (signed contract, scanned contract appendix ))

I have the idea to create separated class files for each class like

for Employee I should create

```
public class EmployeeFile 
{
    public byte[] file { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

for Contract I should create

```
public class ContractFile 
{
     public byte[] file { get; set; }
     public Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

My question is how could I create only one class for File storing to use it for all classes so I will not repeat my self like this class

```
public class File 
{
    public byte[] file { get; set; }
    public Object Object { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it as you want you can use Generics

```
public class File<T> {
    public byte[] file {get;set;}
    public T Host {get;set;}
}
```

Or you can turn it around and add collection property to each class that requires files

```
public class Employee {
    public byte[] file{get;set;}
    public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    public File[] Files{get;set;}
}
```

To make it more generic you can inherit those classes from one general class, or implement interface

```
public interface IFileHolder {
    public File[] Files{get;set;}
}
public class Employee : IFileHolder
```

In case of interface usage you can add to your `File` class function that iterates throug all parents and returns valid one

```
public class File {
    public byte[] file {get;set;}
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public Contract Contract {get;set;}

    public IFileHolder Host{
        get{ return Employee ?? Contract; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , what if i want to save these files into database ,as Employee will save data in a table Employees and the same for other classes Contract and File

Comment: in relational database, which you are most probably using, You would have to create a separate table for `File` that would have a FK to each table, that should use files. In that case class `File` would have to have separate properties for each type of parent object. But in most cases it will be empty, and each of Host objects will have a collection of Files. In that case, if you still need some generalization, you can use interface

Answer (score 0):

Alas, entity framework doesn't work well with generic classes.

However, you could use ASpirin's idea in one of the other answers and derive your concrete classes (= the classes that will be tables) from the generic class, and let your `DbSet` classes of these derived types.

Looking at your design, it seems, that for the time being an `EmployeeFile` has the same structure as a `ContractFile`, so this could work.

But you should also check whether this similar structure is accidentally, or do you really think that every `EmployeeFile` should have the same structure and functionality as a `ContractFile`, now and in future?

If not, reconsider your decision to use generic classes for this.

You will probably perform functions on the DB-side (AsQueryable), and / or in local memory (AsEnumerable). The database queries won't understand the generic classes, so the generic functionality can only be executed AsEnumerable.

Instead of implementing your tables as derived from a generic class, consider extract the things from both classes that are really common as a common base class. The database tables will probably still have a table for `EmployeeFiles` and one for `ContractFiles`. Use [design model Table Per Concrete class (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines).

It is best to let your classes be simple POCOs that are similar to your database tables. This way, these classes can be reused by others that use the same database, without your functionality, which might limit their usage of the data.

You on the other hand can extend the functionality of your POCO classes using extension functions on the class (similar like class `Enumerable` extends the functionality of `IEnumerable`). See [Extension Functions Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)